# Bug in html5 video when overflow is hidden?

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, html, html5-video

I have a div that scrollsDown when called from an Anchor tag and covers 50% of the Div underneath it (using higher z-index). When that div loads via an AJAX call, there is a video that is oversized (min-width: 150%, height: auto).

The overflow setting for the Ajax Div that scrolls down is set to :hidden, however the html5 Video that is playing, subsequently takes up a portion of the entire window where it should be hidden. The video is successfully hidden where it should be and the viewable area is visible. What is driving me crazy is the mouse hit area for where the video isn't showing up, is still registering within the Video's zone (er, hidden visible area).

Currently I'm beating this by forcing the underlying Div to have a higher z-index than the Div which scrollsDown, but it doesn't seem like I should have to do this if the overflow of the Div with video is :hidden.

If interested, please let me know if showing code is necessary. Not posting it as it might be just my grasp of CSS, HTML5 Video and the :overflow value.

This is happening in all broswers being tested:

System OSX (latest update, macbook pro retina)
Chrome, Safari, Firefox, ie3(kidding).

Comment: And the browser[s] this error occurs in?

Comment: ^ Updated to show system specs.